# Low quality question tag?

Tags: feature-request, moderation, reputation, moderators, tagging

This is a duplicate, but answers may very do to each individual SE policy.

I have a positive reputation in science and math there are negatives. I thought I was OK but now I cannot ask questions or revise on poor(which is an opinion of a few not of the many) questions.

The rules are defined, but the most important rules not stated like how many votes can one person give to another? How many "questions received poorly" can be asked before restriction. I just want to know so I know where I stand. The only way I know it is a dumb question if I get comments and down votes.  I know only after its to late. I can change/hide my IP and Email easier than tampering with questions that have an answer.

Moderator don't get paid I appreciate that.

**Can a tag be made to allow lower lever users to answer for other lower level users low quality questions for them and not to bother the high quality users?**

Comment: Saying that one or two people didn't like your questions is selling yourself short. You received warnings from the system that you did not heed. Should the system aid your attempt to find the maximum annoyance tolerated?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's been cross-posted across many meta sites including Meta.SE and nobody here including moderators know the exact rules on question banning.

Comment: @PeterJ see its just easier to close a difficult question then to actually answer it. I was asking the bold questions.

Comment: @Muze this is a network wide thing - you'd be better to post the last part as a discussion on Meta.SE minus the first part about how the current rules work which is what got your last question closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @W5VO I'm not trying to be.

Answer (score 7):

You have a history of asking poor questions.  These get downvoted and/or closed, and the system has locked you out as a result.  This is to protect the site from more of the same crap you've already dumped on it.

The details of the algorithm are not published.  This site isn't a game to see exactly how bad a question you can get away with.

You have posted 7 questions on the main site.  Most have been closed.  The total votes from those question is -17 currently.  That's such a bad record that you have lost the *privilege* of asking here.

Basically, you are not welcome here any more.  Go away.

Comment: Well, you're missing 3 more deleted questions. The real number is -40

Answer (score 6):

This site is about professionalism. The rules are simple here. It's not perfect by any means as you pointed out but it's pretty unambiguous and there's really no reason to dispute ethical decisions. Just because there's no rule dictating what you can and can't doesn't mean you get to be an arbitrator. This isn't philosophy. This is an organized place and it does a darn good job of keeping nonsense out of here (this is my G-rated Disney language LOL). This isn't your website. This is our website. Play by the rules and keep order. The fact that you expect people to conform to your standards is *insane*.

The point of this website is to benefit society and to enlighten people with questions, which you are not doing. There is nothing that you have done that people think, "Wow. I'm sure glad this guy asked this question because I was wondering this same thing." If you want to ask some questionably unintelligent stuff, please go right ahead on Yahoo Answers where people ask the same questions every five seconds. That website is literally riddled with "Am I pregnant?" or "I smoked some weed. Will I pass my drug test?" or "Do you think that (insert politician here) is doing a good job?" etc. We don't need that here. This website is very well known and some employers actually do some searching around on here.

Here's a Dilbert comic on your way out.[image]