# Same mob of people keep closing my questions. Serial closing?

Tags: discussion, scope

When ever I ask a question it is always the same group of people down voting and closing my questions and got my banned on questions. Isn't that serial behavior and is not tolerated?

It may take longer to close, so be it, that way it is sure that the questions was closed with bias. When the same users down vote me, close my question and in some cases answer then close  it so it cannot be deleted makes it serial.

IMO Users who all they do is close questions to get a badge without helping the question first then they are not really helping.

Just because they couldn't answer it doesn't mean someone out there with experience in that question can't. The expert in those fields will never see it if these few close it right away.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you look at the other closed questions, you'll see they most likely have been closed by the same people. This is because there aren't actually many people taking time to keep this site clean (and we should thank them for that). This isn't because they have something against you in particular.

Comment: There aren't thousands of people that do this job. Maby 10 to 20 people do it regularily. This is the people you saw, and you'll see they take care of much much more questions than just yours. Just look at their close-voting history, it should be pretty clear. This isn't serial close-voting. They just do their job, and much likely they don't care who the post is from. If it's bad, they close.

Comment: Because, as I said, they are the people who devote the most time on this job. So, most often, they just happen to be the first persons to look in the close queue. This is just basic probability. Believe me, the questions we're talking about would end up being closed anyway. If these people weren't there, it would simply take a more time. I have actually been impressed on how a natural consensus is easily reached by higher-rep users regarding which questions should be closed. Only few particular cases lead to a debate.

Comment: Many of your questions are highly speculative. You're asking "can this brand new technology be developed?" Problem is, nobody can know the answer to this kind of question without spending a few million dollars trying to develop the technology and either succeeding or failing at it. Of course, you can speculate about what the major roadblocks will be in such an effort, and if you're right you might end up very wealthy. But the site is not intended for open-ended speculation. It's intended for answering questions that have demonstrably correct answers within the bounds of current technology.

Comment: Side note: Please remember that downvotes on Meta don't mean you asked a bad question, they mean the answer to your question is "no, this is not a problem".

Comment: @ThePhoton can some one check my stuff out. I feel that this is a problem. I have been met with hostility on my questions by some users.

Comment: I read three or four of your recent closed question, and my comment above is my feedback on them. This site is not intended to answer these kinds of questions.

Comment: [related](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/81962/6334).

Comment: @ThePhoton love it. If that structure could be built into a blimps skeleton it could draw electricity right out of a thunderstorm in theory.

Comment: @Muze, probably only if the blimp was tethered to the ground.

Comment: @ThePhoton yes for power wire? What size wire? Voltage should be lower in the clouds and more amperage.

Comment: The message I hoped to convey is not that lightning powered blimps were cool, but that many of Tesla's later ideas (which are closely related to what your questions have asked about) are not practical.

Comment: You also don't mention that you have issues with StackExchange sites in general. Should we have suspended you instead?

Comment: @W5VO all of it is to strict. Suspension should only be used when all the other tools available is exhausted.

Comment: @W5VO I love it but some parameters and punishment not so much.

Comment: It's been a while... how have you been? I see you've added more things to your profile picture since the last time I've seen you. Looks like they finally suspended your account. Sorry to hear that. But this'll give you more time to meditate and reflect on your mistakes. We all get smarter in a single year after learning new things in life. Hope you learn new things. Seeya next year!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The same "mob" of people are closing a whole lot of bad questions. Your questions are closed because they are bad, not because someone has something personal against you.

Your only open [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/356366/mending-broken-solar-cells) so far seems decent, although it could use some more details. As you can see, there's no "angry mob" voting to close it, because it's not a hypothetical crank-physics question like the rest, but an actual practical problem you are having, related to electrical engineering.

(Sadly, people insist on "answering" the questions in the *comment* field, which is why you don't have an answer yet.)

Comment: personal or not if the same person helps close more than half of my questions seem serial statistically.

Comment: I wouldn't say angry more hasty.

Answer (score 2):

So, you had a choice of courses of action on getting your questions closed do you:-

a) Try to learn from the experience and stop posting nonsense or ridiculously broad unanswerable questions.

or

b) Accuse the volunteers here who are freely giving their time and effort of picking on you.

Can I suggest that you give this matter a bit more thought. Several very senior people on this site have already given their opinion as per Olin's answer [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6416/why-is-this-question-still-gettng-downvotedalthough) it appears that I am not allowed to express the same sentiments.